# FastRemoveObject in CCArray will change the positions of objects?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I was told that if relying on a specific ordering of objects, I should not use the fastRemoveObject methods in CCArray. Cocos2d API references don't show the contents of the method specifically. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, fastRemoveObject changes the order of nodes. It is therefore not recommended unless it really doesn't matter in your case.

What it does is the following:

- assign object at last index to index of object being removed
- nil last object
- decrease array count

That way the array will not have to perform memory operations (hence: fast). But the last object will now be at the index of the removed object.